# React: Unable to import images this way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Title working well, but why images are not showing? What should I do?

```js
const Card = () => {
    const IMAGES = {
        logo: require("../image/watchImg/image 2.jpg").default,
        title: "murshida",
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Latest Products Slider</h2>
            <div className="container">
                <img src={IMAGES.logo} alt="" />
                <h2>{IMAGES.title}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)? Normally you just import the image file at the top of your module... `import logo from "../image/watchImg/image 2.jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

require function should be in src . and removespace and .default for path. check image name . its should not have space . use this way ...

```
const IMAGES = {
    logo: "../image/watchImg/image2.jpg",
    title: "murshida",
}

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Latest Products Slider</h2>
        <div className="container">
            <img src={require(IMAGES.logo)} alt="" />
            <h2>{IMAGES.title}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

);
```